# Create MSI Installer for Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-installer, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to create windows' MSI installer for Xamarin form Apps Windows store? because some of our apps users disable windows store because of that can't install the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make an MSI for a UWP app (that it is a UWP built with XAmarin Forms is inconsequential), but you can sideload UWP apps or even install them from a web page. 
See this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

and to install from a web page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/installing-uwp-apps-web

And a more general doc on installing UWP apps outside of the store:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/appinstaller-root